# WPF DataGrid group header: selectable and change color on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a list of items in a WPF DataGrid. In group mode I want do highlight the color of the group header and for Drag-Drop the header should be selectable.

I think, I have to make a usercontrol depending on Expander, because the Expander himself has no IsSelected flag.
For the beginning I tried to change the color of the Expander header, but I only could do that for a StackPanel containing the text for the group property and the items count.

I changed the StackPanel to a Grid so the grouping property and the item count are better formated.

The IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged Event is not fired.

```
                    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <Expander Background="#1E90FF" BorderBrush="Gray" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0 0 0 3" IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged="Expander_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged">
                                                    <Expander.Header>
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Expander.Header>
                                                    <Expander.Content>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                                    </Expander.Content>
                                                </Expander>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Any idea how to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it to work with XAML, but with code-behind with Expander MouseEnter & MouseLeave.
Not very elegant, but it works.